# Showing $\lim_{x,y,z\to(0,0,0)}\frac{x^2 + 2y^2-3yz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to figure out why this limit is 0.

$\lim_{x,y,z\to(0,0,0)}\frac{x^2 + 2y^2-3yz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$

It has been suggested I bound the absolute value below by zero, and above by $5\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ and then take limits, but I don't see how to show that $\frac{x^2+2y^2-3yz}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ is bounded from above by $5$.

Comment: Try looking at it in spherical coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=r$. Then $|x|,|y|,|z|\leqslant r$ and therefore$$|x^2+2y^2-3yz|\leqslant6r^2,$$and so$$\left|\frac{x^2+2y^2-3yz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right|\leqslant 6r.$$So, given $\varepsilon>0$, if you take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon6$, then\begin{align}\bigl\|(x,y,z)\bigr\|<\delta&\implies\bigl\|(x,y,z)\bigr\|=r\text{ for some }r<\delta\\&\implies\left|\frac{x^2+2y^2-3yz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right|\leqslant 6r<6\delta\\&\implies\left|\frac{x^2+2y^2-3yz}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\right|<\varepsilon.\end{align}